# Updating table with the closest value from a lookup matrix

Tags: sql, sql-server, matrix, sql-update, lookup-tables

## TABLE 1

First table is the matrix containing reference values, something like this:

```
create table dm_matrix
(x float,
z float,
avgValue float)


insert into dm_matrix values (1,1, rand())
insert into dm_matrix values (1,2, rand())
...
insert into dm_matrix values (4,3, rand())
insert into dm_matrix values (4,4, rand())
```

Creating a matrix like this one

```
z\x |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |
-----------------------------
  1 |  .1 |  .7 |  .3 |  .2 |
  2 |  .5 |  .1 |  .8 |  .6 |
  3 |  .6 |  .2 |  .3 |  .9 |
  4 |  .4 |  .3 |  .3 |  .5 |
```

## TABLE 2

Second table is the list of events with their coordinates:

```
create table dm_values 
(vx float,
vz float,
v float)

insert into dm_values (vx, vz) values (1 + rand()*3, 1 + rand()*3)
...
insert into dm_values (vx, vz) values (1 + rand()*3, 1 + rand()*3)
```

So the entries have the coordinates, but no values for the events

```
   vx  |  vz  |   v   |
-----------------------
  1.3  |  2.7 |  null |
  2.6  |  2.7 |  null |
  1.3  |  3.3 |  null |
  1.9  |  1.1 |  null |
  3.0  |  2.9 |  null |
  ...  |  ... |   ... |
```

## TASK

I want to update my second table with the closest value from the first one. So for the first entry (x = 1.3, z = 2.7) I would want the value to be updated to the one from the lookup matrix where x = 1 and z = 3 (.6). The updated table would then look like this:

```
   vx  |  vz  |   v   |
-----------------------
  1.3  |  2.7 |   0.6 |
  2.6  |  2.7 |   0.3 |
  1.3  |  3.3 |   0.6 |
  1.9  |  1.1 |   0.7 |
  3.0  |  2.9 |   0.3 |
  ...  |  ... |   ... |
```

## PROBLEM

I can get this -- in theory -- to work with cursors. But my TABLE 1 has some 2000 rows (~50x40) and my TABLE 2 rows are in low millions. Cursor approach would take days, weeks or months to complete. I need a better performing solution and am grateful for any tips.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. +1 for asking your first question properly.

Comment: How about a Function - that will take vx and vz, round it then return the value?

Comment: with table 1, are you doing some pivoting to produce that table? or do you actually store the values in x, z & avg columns like the script suggests?

Comment: Not sure how to answer to a comment directly, so:

1) Thanks for the welcome

2) I create the lookup table by averaging certain property of the table 2, split by areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, you should be able to perform a simple `UPDATE` using a `JOIN`, where you `ROUND` the values of `vx` and `vz` for the `JOIN` condition, performance wise, you'd have to test this on your dataset though.

Here's the basic method to `JOIN` the data, note I've padded out the `INSERT` scripts to have a complete matrix:

```
CREATE TABLE #dm_matrix
    (
      x FLOAT ,
      z FLOAT ,
      avgValue DECIMAL(2, 1)
    )


INSERT  INTO #dm_matrix
VALUES  ( 1, 1, RAND() )
INSERT  INTO #dm_matrix
VALUES  ( 1, 2, RAND() )
INSERT  INTO #dm_matrix
VALUES  ( 1, 3, RAND() )
INSERT  INTO #dm_matrix
VALUES  ( 1, 4, RAND() )
INSERT  INTO #dm_matrix
VALUES  ( 2, 1, RAND() )
INSERT  INTO #dm_matrix
VALUES  ( 2, 2, RAND() )
INSERT  INTO #dm_matrix
VALUES  ( 2, 3, RAND() )
INSERT  INTO #dm_matrix
VALUES  ( 2, 4, RAND() )
INSERT  INTO #dm_matrix
VALUES  ( 3, 1, RAND() )
INSERT  INTO #dm_matrix
VALUES  ( 3, 2, RAND() )
INSERT  INTO #dm_matrix
VALUES  ( 3, 3, RAND() )
INSERT  INTO #dm_matrix
VALUES  ( 3, 4, RAND() )
INSERT  INTO #dm_matrix
VALUES  ( 4, 1, RAND() )
INSERT  INTO #dm_matrix
VALUES  ( 4, 2, RAND() )
INSERT  INTO #dm_matrix
VALUES  ( 4, 3, RAND() )
INSERT  INTO #dm_matrix
VALUES  ( 4, 4, RAND() )

SELECT  *
FROM    #dm_matrix

CREATE TABLE #dm_values
    (
      vx DECIMAL(2, 1) ,
      vz DECIMAL(2, 1) ,
      v FLOAT
    )

INSERT  INTO #dm_values
        ( vx, vz )
VALUES  ( 1 + RAND() * 3, 1 + RAND() * 3 )
INSERT  INTO #dm_values
        ( vx, vz )
VALUES  ( 1 + RAND() * 3, 1 + RAND() * 3 )

SELECT  *
FROM    #dm_values

-- replace this SELECT with the UPDATE commands below to update values
SELECT  v.vx ,
        v.vz ,
        m.avgValue
FROM    #dm_values v
        INNER JOIN #dm_matrix m ON ROUND(v.vx, 0) = m.x
                                   AND ROUND(v.vz, 0) = m.z

DROP TABLE #dm_matrix
DROP TABLE #dm_values
```

And for the `UPDATE` you would do something like this:

```
UPDATE v
SET v.v = m.avgValue
FROM #dm_values v 
INNER JOIN #dm_matrix m ON ROUND(v.vx, 0) = m.x AND ROUND(v.vz, 0) = m.z

SELECT * FROM #dm_values
```

**Produces:**

**Matrix:**

```
x   z   avgValue
1   1   0.6
1   2   0.9  -- row 2 below
1   3   0.4
1   4   0.5
2   1   0.7
2   2   0.4
2   3   0.5  -- row 1 below
2   4   0.5
3   1   0.4
3   2   0.1
3   3   0.3
3   4   0.8
4   1   0.1
4   2   1.0
4   3   0.5
4   4   0.5
```

**Values:**

```
vx  vz  v
1.8 2.8 NULL  -- x = 2, z = 3
1.3 1.5 NULL  -- x = 1, z = 2
```

**After Update:**

```
vx  vz  v
1.8 2.8 0.5
1.3 1.5 0.9
```

**NOTE:**

I've changed the data type to `DECIMAL(2, 1)` for the purpose of this post, so you may need to modify this based on your actual dataset.

Comment: Duh! Of course, rounding! Sometimes there are so simple and beautiful solutions to what I make to be complex problems. Thanks, dear Sir

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use `cross apply` or a correlated subquery for this.

```
update t2
    set v = m.avgvalue
    from t2 cross apply
         (select top 1 m.*
          from dm_matrix
          order by square(m.x - t2.vx) + square(m.z - t2.vz)
         );
```

I'm not sure what function you are using for distance, but Euclidean distance seems like a reasonable interpretation.

Comment: Thanks. This is probably a better generic approach, but as the values in my matrix lookup table are equidistant and rounded, the more specific solution of just rounding the values will do the trick for me as well

Comment: @vori . . . Be careful with the use of floating point numbers for this purpose.  If you work things out correctly, you may be able to make use of an index.